# How to get all the elements from array of tuples matching String?

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

i have a array of tuple like

```
var contactsname = [(String,String)]()//firstname,lastname
```

example =     [(alex,joe),(catty,drling),(alex,fox),(asta,alex)]

i need to search elements which are matching the firstname or lastname and return those all elements matching the key

```
func searchElementsForkey(key:String)->[(string,String)]{ //code here }
```

searchElementsForKey("alex") = [(alex,joe),(alex,fox),(asta,alex)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go like this.

```
var contactsname = [(String,String)]()//firstname,lastname
contactsname = [("alex","joe"),("catty","drling"),("alex","fox"),("asta","alex")]
let key = "alex"
```

If you want to exact match the search name either with First name or Last name

```
let filterArray = contactsname.filter { $0.0 == key || $0.1 == key }
```

If you want to check First name and Last name contains specific string for that you can use `contains`

```
let filterArray = contactsname.filter { $0.0.contains(key) || $0.1.contains(key) }
```

Comment: Does this code still work in the newer swift version? I'm getting 4 errors? Cannot assign to property: '$0' is immutable; Cannot assign value of type 'Bool' to type 'String'; Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Bool';Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Bool'

Comment: @brockhampton It was typo mistake, it should be `$0.0 == key` not `$0.0 = key`