# Swift - Search and Replace value in Tuple

Tags: swift, search, replace, tuples

I have tuple of kind: `[(id:String, name:String, years:Int, city:String)]`

What should I do to search for certain `id` and to change the `city` of that `id`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all the elements from array of tuples matching String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935024/how-to-get-all-the-elements-from-array-of-tuples-matching-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search an array of tuples using [`firstIndex(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex) to find the index of the first element to match your condition.  In your case, you are looking to match a specific `id`, so you would use a closure such as `{ $0.id == "2" }`.

Once you find that index, you can use it to update the tuple inside of the array.

**Example:**

```
var info: [(id: String, name: String, years: Int, city: String)] = [
    ("1", "Fred", 35, "Bedrock"),
    ("2", "Wilma", 32, "Bedrock")
]

if let idx = info.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == "2" }) {
    info[idx].city = "Boulder"
}

print(info)
```

**Output**

> ```
> [(id: "1", name: "Fred", years: 35, city: "Bedrock"),
>  (id: "2", name: "Wilma", years: 32, city: "Boulder")]
> ```

---

**Use a `struct` instead of a tuple**

That said, you should really use a `struct` here to contain your values.  Tuples in Swift are really meant for temporary use (such as returning multiple values from a function), so defining a `struct` to hold your values is preferred:

```
struct Record {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var years: Int
    var city: String
}


var info: [Record] = [
    .init(id: "1", name: "Fred", years: 35, city: "Bedrock"),
    .init(id: "2", name: "Wilma", years: 32, city: "Bedrock")
]
```

The searching code would remain the same.